# Zend Framework 1 apache2 vhost configuration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, apache2

Today I uploaded my Zend Framework 1 web project to my web server (debian) with apache2 running on it.

I developed the project on a mac with XAMPP. 
I copied the configuration to the vhost and .htaccess-file.

`vhost (/etc/apache2/sites-available/***.***.de.conf)`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName ****.****.de

ServerAdmin ******@******.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/****.****.de/public_html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/****.****.de/public_html>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

.htaccess (in public_html)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This is what I got from many different sources and after searching for hours this worked for my local development environment. When I open the website, I can see the start page. But controller calls do not work (except the index controller). I always get the error "Not Found".

In /etc/apache2/ports.conf I added

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Of course I've added the website via a2ensite and restarted the apache2 web server.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Check that the rewrite module is enabled in Apache (`a2enmod rewrite` probably) and restart again

Comment: I did not check this, but after enabling rewrite module it still does not work (same errors as before).

Comment: OK now I tried to test if the .htaccess is even working and added a permanent redirect (RewriteRule .* http://www.neuedomain.tld/ [L,R=301]), but it doesn't work. So it seems that the .htaccess is not even used?

Answer (score 2):

So after recognizing that the .htaccess is not even working (by simply setting a redirect to any domain) I found the solution:

Open /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and edit the directory setting for /var/www as following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart apache

```
service apache2 reload
```

I'm not sure if this is a good solution, but for me it works.

Comment: It makes sense, if your version of apache is >= 2.4, the instructions "Order allow,deny" and "Allow from all" are useless. Since this version, you have to use "Require all granted", or "Require local", or whatever you want to grant, to make it work. Nice job finding this out though !